# trying to write to c:\temp in my console app

Tags: c#

I have a very simple console app where I'm using

```
dataset.WriteXml(@"c:\temp")
```

but I'm getting message "Access Denied". What do I need to do?

Using Visual Studio 2008 on XP Pro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to write to "c:\temp" which I suspect is a directory. Try:

```
dataset.WriteXml(@"c:\temp\dataset.xml")
```

Comment: That's it, thanks for the catch. I'll mark it as soon as I can, rod.

Answer (score 3):

If you're just trying to create a temporary file, rather than using C:\Temp, which may not be writable depending on user privileges, use Path.GetTempFileName(). This will return a filename in the user's \AppData\Local\Temp directory, which the user can write to.